# Center of mass for a homogenous cube without one side

Tags: mass, coordinate-systems

I have a cube, with a side of 50. The only point is that the top of the cube doesn't exist.
[image]

What I have in mind was that because the cube is homogeneous then the x and y part of the center of mass are definitely at 25cm and 25 cm. Then I had a hypothesis and it was that because it has 6 sides, and 1 side doesn't exist, then the mass is actually 5/6 of a full cube, but I'm not sure if I'm on the right path.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that the cube is homogeneous is important.

When you have an object which is formed by some parts, there is an interesting property:

The CM of the whole object can be obtained if you know the CM of each individual piece. The CM of the pieces are like point particles storing all the mass of the piece. Consequently, you can forget about the pieces and just think of a system of point particles, plaed on the individual CMs.

In simple words, you know that each side of the cube is a uniform rectangle. The CM of each side is at the center of the side.

Therefore, you've got 5 points, which are the CM of each side. Those 5 poitns can be considered to be 5 particles, each one having the mass of its corresponding side.

**So, you only have to compute the CM of 5 point particles.**

---

There's another trick: you can also consider an entire cube and add an extra side with "negative mass", so that you compensate the hollow side.

Comment: This is the classiest answer so far, tho' to be fair the other answers also make use of the "sum of CMs" rule.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a very simple way to answer this.

Think of this as 2 masses .
Mass A is the lower face ( say m kg ), and Mass B is the other 4 faces ( say 4m kg )

Then center of mass of A  is ( 25,25,0 )

Center of mass of B is ( 25,25,25 )

So,now you can just calculate center of mass as if these were 2 point particles

point A with m kg at ( 25,25,0 ) and point B with 4m kg at ( 25,25,25 )

So, the center of mass will be at ( 25 , 25 , (m*0 + 4m *25)/5m ) = ( 25,25, 20 )

Answer (score 1):

To answer the main question, i.e. if you are on the right path or not, yes you are.

Let me assume the total mass of the cube *without missing a side* is **M**, and **M = 6m**.
So now removing one side, your cube has a mass of 5m. Now, look at the cube from z-axis. What you see, is a symmetrical distribution of mass about the point (25, 25, 0), just as you saw in the case of the full cube. That means, that the COM would still lie at (25, 25, **r**), where r is the z- co-ordinate, which is what we need to find for the sake of completion of the answer.

Still with me? Well, instead of a cube with one side missing, assume that the cube is closed, with mass **M** (ofcourse), and that you put a slab of mass **-m**, superimposed with the top sheet. This brings us back to the situation we had in the original problem.

Now to find the COM (one step left), I must point out that the COM of the full solid cube is at (25, 25, 25), which you would have expected, and the COM of the negative mass slab is at (25, 25, 50). Try to see if this makes sense.

So on to find the **r** value.

r = [ (6mx25) + (**-m**x50) ]/[ 6m + **-m** ]
=> r = 20 units

So your hollow cube would have it's COM located at (25, 25, 20).

I hope this helps.